# Cannot open SCTP Socket with socket type SOCK_DGRAM

Tags: c++, sockets, centos, udp, sctp

```
int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
```

the returned error is 93 on CentOS 3.2.63 and 10043 on windows 8 which means Protocol not supported. But I can open the socket successfully with socket type SOCK_RAW,SOCK_STREAM. Can't open with SOCK_SEQPACKET in windows 8 but can open in CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCTP must be used with either SOCK_SEQPACKET or SOCK_STREAM. See [Sockets API Extensions for the Stream Control Transmission Protocol (SCTP), RFC 6458](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6458) for more details on how to use SCTP.

Not all OS support SCTP and even existing support might miss some features.

Comment: If I don't want to use thirdparty library then I have to implement SCTP on my own on windows platform?

Comment: Yes, there does not seem to be native support for it.